# Why geometries disappear at some zoom levels in iOS devices?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I work on a web application that uses Geoserver and OpenLayers. Geometries are rendered using WMS from Geoserver and they are rendered correctly at all zoom levels (28 zoom levels in total) in computers.

However, when using the application on iPhones and zoom to certain zoom levels such as 17 or 19, the geometries all disappeared but they will appear again if zooming further (e.g., 18 or 20 and further). I wonder if anyone has any idea what could be the root cause issue here?

This is what it looks like when working properly:
[image: This is what it looks like when working properly]

And on iPhones, they will all disappear like this:
[image: And on iPhones, they will all disappear like this]

I tried to change the resolutions, and change maxZoom but they didn't work. I also check the SLD in Geoserver but they all use the same SLD. The only difference is that PCs and iPhones.

Comment: Possibly related to limited canvas resources in IOS as discussed in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14555